# SocketIO 1.3.2 remove listner, Client Side

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

How can i remove specific listeners on client socket. I need to remove the listener because this controller can be initialized multiple times. and i don't want to add new listener to the socket every time controller is initialized.

```
function EventMessagesController($scope,socket, $rootScope) {

socket.on('message', function (message) {
     //Handle messsage
})

$scope.$on("$destroy",
    function handleDestroyEvent() {
        socket.manager().removeListner('message');
    }
);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Socket IO documentation is not the clearest and i cant figure out the answer in the source code.

Comment: You shouldn't be initializing socket event from inside the controller to begin with. Move it out to a service and require that service into your app instead of the controller.. or something like that, with the main aim being that it only gets called once, independent of routes and/or controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A socket.io socket is an `eventEmitter` so you can see the various ways to remove an event listener [here in the doc for eventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener).

You have options to use:

```
 socket.removeListener(event, listener)
 socket.removeAllListeners([event])
```

Note: in the code in your question `removeListner` is misspelled.